# 2 SQL Server Databases in Django Project

Tags: sql-server, django, django-settings

I have a problem loading data in database1 (default). You see, the system only has to load data that is in the database2 (source). the system works in the machine of my confessor but it has two different ports loaded and uses docker, I have the SQL server installed. The system starts, the problem is that when I want to load a data in the database1 it tells me that this data does not exist in the database2, then it does not. Now, if I try to load data that is not in the database2 if it loads correctly. I searched how to change the ports of the SQL Server but I did not get it. Can anyone help me?

```
DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
            'NAME': 'database1',
            'HOST': 'name\\name',
            'PORT': '',
            'USER': 'user1',
            'PASSWORD': 'password1',
            'OPTIONS': {
                'driver': 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server',
            }
        },
        'source': {
            'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
            'NAME': 'database2',
            'HOST': 'name\\name',
            'PORT': '',
            'USER': 'user2',
            'PASSWORD': 'password2',
            'OPTIONS': {
                'driver': 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server',
            }
        }
```

Comment: How did you setup your database routers? You have to create a router to tell django which database to use when. See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/multi-db/#using-routers)

Answer (score 0):

This is the configuration:
`def decide_on_model(model):
    """Small helper function to pipe all DB operations of a worlddata model to the world_data DB"""
    return 'source' if model._meta.app_label == 'source' else None`

`class TutoriasRouter:
    """
    Implements a database router so that:`

```
* Django related data - DB alias `default` - MySQL DB `world_django`
* Legacy "world" database data (everything "non-Django") - DB alias `world_data` - MySQL DB `world`
"""
def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
    return decide_on_model(model)

# def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
#     return decide_on_model(model)

def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
    return 'default'

def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
    # Allow any relation if both models are part of the worlddata app
    # if obj1._meta.app_label == 'source' and obj2._meta.app_label == 'source':
    #     return True
    # # Allow if neither is part of worlddata app
    # elif 'source' not in [obj1._meta.app_label, obj2._meta.app_label]:
    #     return True
    # # by default return None - "undecided"
    return True

def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
    # allow migrations on the "default" (django related data) DB
    if db == 'default' and app_label != 'source':
        return True

    # allow migrations on the legacy database too:
    # this will enable to actually alter the database schema of the legacy DB!

    # if db == 'source' and app_label == "source":
    #    return True

    return False
```

`